# Regex cron. Detect if below 5 minutes

Tags: regex, cron

I have this regex:

```
^\h*(?:(?:\*|[0-9]+)\/0*(?:[0-4]))(?:\s+\*){4}
```

And I have these strings of cron jobs:

```
2,5,8,27,30,36,12,15,18,21,24,39,42 * * * * /bin/echo 0
5,5,8,27,30,36,12,15,18,21,24,39,42 * * * * /bin/echo 0
200,5,8,27,30,36,12,15,18,21,24,39,42 * * * * /bin/echo 0
27,30,36,12,15,18,21,24,39,42 * * * * /bin/echo 0
*/16 * * * * /bin/echo 0
*/13 * * * * /bin/echo 0
*/4 * * * * /bin/echo 0
*/2 * * * * /bin/echo 0
*/3 * * * * /bin/echo 0
110,5,8,27,30,36,12,15,18,21,24,39,42 * * * * /bin/echo 0
```

The result of the regex above is:

```
*/4 * * * * /bin/echo 0
*/2 * * * * /bin/echo 0
*/3 * * * * /bin/echo 0
```

But it does not detect other cron jobs that run below 4 minutes like this:

`2,5,8,27,30,36,12,15,18,21,24,39,42 * * * * /bin/echo 0`

So that one runs every 2 minutes, 5 minutes, 27, etc.

I would like to detect all lines of cron jobs that run below 5 minutes.

You can see my regex example here: https://regex101.com/r/iJmdvl/1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what are you trying to return on this? "2,5,8,27,30,36,12,15,18,21,24,39,42 * * * * /bin/echo 0" - just detect it? or are you trying to return the timing? ... on your regex101 example, you are only matching 3 of the 10 lines - are you trying to return the timing/detect all of the lines? ... can you please clarify your question more?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am trying to return all numbers (per row) that has mora than 5 and up. so "2,5,8,27,30,36,12,15,18,21,24,39,42 * * * * /bin/echo 0" should return but not "5,5,8,27,30,36,12,15,18,21,24,39,42 * * * * /bin/echo 0" becuse that one have that number "5,5" My goal is to return/detect a line/row that has a number with more than 5.

Comment: ok so the lines that start with 27, 110, 200, 5, */16, */13 should all not return, but if the lines start with 1, 2, 3, 4, */1, */2, */3, */4 then it should return

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here give this a try -

`^(\*?\/?[0-4])(?:\s|,)`

Which can be tested here -

https://regex101.com/r/U1MzYt/1/

This will just match the first part of each line if it contains */ conditionally and if it's followed (or starts with) [0-4].

Comment: @JohnMark - if you are happy with the answer, please feel free to accept it with the "tick box" - good luck and let me know if you have any other questions : )